# save command out to variable and show command output without waiting for it to complete

Tags: linux, bash

Then I call command in my bash script like `command` it's outputs to my terminal but isn't saving anywhere. If I want to save output I use `output=$(command)` but now command output isn't showing to my screen unless `command` would be completed so I can call `echo "${output}"`. But the problem is: I don't want to wait until command will be completed. So, is there any way to call `command`, show output while it's running and later save everything to a variable?

It could work, if I call it twice:

```
command
output=$(command)
```

but it's not that good I think.

sry for my engrish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a tool called `tee`:

> The tee utility copies standard input to standard output, making a copy in zero 
>   or more files.  The output is unbuffered.

It will output to the screen and also to a file. you use it like this:

```
cat file1.txt | tee -a file2.txt
```

Use of `cat` is just an example. Any command on the left side of the pipe should work.

Comment: `output=$(command | tee /dev/fd/2)` is more appropriate; the OP isn't indicating anywhere that they want to save to a file.

Comment: Also, questions that already exist in the knowledgebase should be flagged as duplicate, not answered; that way folks get the most complete answers possible, already vetted/edited/amended/etc. If the answers on an existing duplicate aren't as good as what you'd write yourself, flag-as-duplicate and add your answer on that prospective duplicate itself.

Comment: Charles duffy, thanks. That is definitely what I've needed.